# Passing list of coulmns and Values in postgresql query

Tags: python, postgresql

db=postgresql 13

language= python

i have table name = "abc"

```
coulmn_name=[question_1,question_2,question_3,.....,question_50]
column_values=[1,2,3,......,50]
```

I need to write a postgresql query to store these values in respective column names basically i need to take list parameters in my query. i have connected to the database using pyscopg2 and i am able to excute queries too. but manually writing column names:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user_responses("question_1","question_2","question_3","question_4","question_5","question_6","question_7","question_8","question_9","question_10","question_11","question_12","question_13","question_14","question_15","question_16","question_17","question_18","question_19","question_20","question_21","question_22","question_23","question_24","question_25","question_26","question_27","question_28","question_29","question_30","question_31","question_32","question_33","question_34","question_35","question_36","question_37","question_38","question_39","question_40","question_41","question_42","question_43","question_44","question_45","question_46","question_47","question_48","question_49","question_50") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',column_values)
```

above query is working but it is not the correct way i guess .
I need something where i can pass list of column names.

```
       sql_string='INSERT INTO {} '.format(column_name)
```

how can i proceed further?please help.

Comment: `psycopg2` is the library you have to use to read and write to a Postgres database. Read the docs to get started - https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `INSERT INTO ({})` not `INSERT INTO {}`. Column names have to be inside round braces.

```
columns = ["question_1", "question_2", "question_3"]

sql_string = """INSERT INTO user_responses({}) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""".format(','.join(columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

'One simple way is to convert your values to tuple for column use string'

> coulmn_name=','.join([q1,q2,q3,.....,q50])

> column_values=tuple([1,2,3,......,50])

Assuming above list index and value are in right sequence

> sql_string="INSERT INTO TABLE_XYZ ({}) VALUES {};".format(column_name, column_values)

Comment: syntax error at or near "'question'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO user_responses ( 'question_1', '..

Comment: I have written like this column_name = ["q1","q2","q3"] because column_name=[q1,q2,q3] is giving me error undefined error q1,q2

Comment: @AlokSharma yes for column you need to format string differently, Check updated Answer